# How can we differentiate twice the trace of pullback metric via a flow?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$
$\renewcommand{\div}{\operatorname{div}}$

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold. Given a vector field  $X$ on $M$, Let $\psi_t:M \to M$ be the flow of $X$.

Is there a reasonable way to express $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial  t^2}\left|_{t=0}\right.\tr_g\big((\psi_t^*g)_p\big)$?

If we denote $f(t,p)=\tr_g\big((\psi_t^*g)_p\big)$ then $\frac{\partial }{\partial  t}f(t,p)=\tr_g(\psi_t^*L_Xg)$. (In particular, $\frac{\partial }{\partial  t}f(0,p)=\tr_g(L_Xg)=2\div (X)$.)

So, the question is how to obtain an expression for $\frac{\partial }{\partial  t} \tr_g(\psi_t^*L_Xg)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you wtite down is the trace of the second Lie derivative of the metric $\operatorname{tr}_g(\mathcal{L}_X(\mathcal{L}_Xg))$. This can be rewritten a bit using properties of the Lie derivative. Let $\hat{g}$ be the inverse metric. The trace $\operatorname{tr}_g$ can be seen as a tensor product with $\hat{g}$ followed by a contraction $\delta:T^2_2 M\to\mathbb{R}$. We can use this to expand the expression, since $\mathcal{L}_X$ commutes with contractions and distributes over tensor products.
$$
\operatorname{Tr}_g(\mathcal{L}_X(\mathcal{L}_Xg))=\delta[\hat{g}\otimes\mathcal{L}_X(\mathcal{L}_X(g))] \\
=\delta[\mathcal{L}_X(\mathcal{L}_X(\hat{g}\otimes g))-\mathcal{L}_X(\mathcal{L}_X\hat{g}\otimes g)-\mathcal{L}_X\hat{g}\otimes\mathcal{L}_Xg] \\
=\mathcal{L}_X(\mathcal{L}_X(\delta(\hat{g}\otimes g)))-\mathcal{L}_X(\delta(\mathcal{L}_X\hat{g}\otimes g))-\delta(\mathcal{L}_X\hat{g}\otimes\mathcal{L}_Xg) \\
$$
The first term vanishes, since it is the lie derivative of the constant function $\operatorname{tr}_gg$. The other two can be written as
$$
=-\mathcal{L}_X((\mathcal{L}_X\hat{g})^{ij}g_{ij})-(\mathcal{L}_X\hat{g})^{ij}(\mathcal{L}_Xg)_{ij}
$$
Then using the fact that $(\mathcal{L}_X\hat{g})^{ij}=-\hat{g}^{ik}\hat{g}^{jl}(\mathcal{L}_Xg)_{kl}$ (which can be seen by differentiating the expression $\hat{g}^{ij}g_{jk}=\delta^i_k$), we get
$$
=\mathcal{L}_X(\hat{g}^{ij}(\mathcal{L}_Xg)_{ij})+\hat{g}^{ik}\hat{g}^{jl}(\mathcal{L}_Xg)_{ij}(\mathcal{L}_Xg)_{kl}
$$
Finally, using Killing's equation $(\mathcal{L}_X g)_{ij}=X_{i;j}+X_{j;i}$
$$
=2X^jX^i_{;ij}+2g_{ij}\hat{g}^{kl}X^i_{;k}X^j_{;l}+2X^i_{;j}X^j_{;i}
$$
Or, in more coordinate free notation:
$$
=2X(\operatorname{div}X)+2\|\nabla X\|^2+2\operatorname{tr}(\nabla X\circ\nabla X)
$$
Where $\|\ \ \|$ is the norm on $(1,1)$ tensors induced by $g$ and $\circ$ is composition of $(1,1)$ tensors, thought of as fiberwise linear maps $TM\to TM$.

Comment: Hi, I know this has been posted some time ago, but revisiting your answer, I am a little confused about something: what is your coordinate-invariant interpretation of the inverse metric $\hat g$? do you view $g$ as a map $V \to V^*$ and its inverse $V^* \to V$ or something like that? Similarly, I am not sure what is the contraction $\delta$ you are referring to (I am not sure what the symbol $T^2_2 M$ means. I do know that for $A \in V^* \otimes V^*$, we have $\text{tr}_g(A)=\langle g,A \rangle =g^{ij}A_{ij}$, so is that you mean?

Comment: I guess that I am asking if there is a coordinate-invariant way to phrase your solution?

Comment: To you fist point, $\hat{g}$ is indeed the inverse of the map $g$, interpreted as a fiberwise linear isomorphism $TM\to T^*M$. This makes $\hat{g}:T^*M\to TM$ a $(0,2)$ tensor. To the second, by $T^2_2M$ I mean the space of $(2,2)$ tensors on $TM$, and the contraction $\delta$ is given in coordinates by $\delta(T)=T^{ij}{}_{ij}$. The coordinate free interpretation is that for $u,v\in T_pM$ and $\mu,\nu\in T_p^*M$ we define$$\delta(u\otimes v\otimes\mu\otimes\nu)=\mu(u)\nu(v)$$and extend $\delta$ to the rest of $T^2_2M$ by linearity.

Comment: As for coordinate invariance, the computations above can be interpreted as [abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation), which is coordinate-free. In other schemes of notation it can be difficult to deal with all of the raising/lowering/contraction/braiding maps on the tensor spaces.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very good explanation! I would still prefer to find an index-free approach, but perhaps that would be too much to ask.